# create-react-app Webpack devtool = "source-map" not generating *.map files

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, source-maps

I am trying to enable source map on an older React app written in 2017. I've previously was able to configure enabling source maps on newer React apps post 2021 onwards by toggling the environment variable REACT_APP_GENERATE_SOURCEMAP to either true of false. However this does **not** work with the older app create in 2017.

I have also tried passing in devtool source-map as params to npm build such as:

```
npm run build -- --devtool source-map
```

However that is also **not** working.

Older app that I am referring to is using Web 4 and create-react-app version is 1.1.10
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/compare/v1.0.10...v5.0.1

Lastly, this older app does not use react-script eject so the webpack config  is encapsulated and not externally configurable (as far as I know).

Anyone has encountered this and have solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to find this after scouring the net for possible answers:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7960

Basically the issue was UglifyPlugin that has sourceMap = false. Given that our app doesn't use eject, I had to 'rewire' (or override) the webpack config using this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire

My JS code to override:

```
const rw= require('rewire');
const defaults = rw('xxx-react-scripts/scripts/build.js');
const cfg= defaults.__get__('config');

  cfg.plugins.forEach((r) => {
    if (r.options.uglifyOptions) {
      console.log(r);
      console.log('Found UglifyPlugin - rewiring UglifyPlugin config to enable sourceMap');
      r.options.sourceMap = true;
    }
  });
```